# setting height of multiple images via jquery?

Tags: jquery, height

I have an image on a page that I would like to set the height of that equal to the parent container.  If you take this page for example, http://myrtlebeachgolfpackages.com/packages/ ,the main images on the left, I want to fill the height 100% of their respective divs.

So my thought is to grab the height of the parent container and set the height of the image equal to that parent container.

```
$(".packagepic").height($('this').parent().parent().height());
```

The layout is basically

```
<div>
    <a>
        <image class="packagepic">
    </a>
</div>
```

which is why I am grabbing `parent().parent()`.

However, of course you can see this is not working. Please also note that I cant set the height of ALL the divs to one height, or ALL the images to a certain height because the height of their respective divs changes depending on the package.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
$(".packagepic").height(function () {
    return $(this).parent().parent().height();
});
```

Comment: i'll give you the prize since you answered first. :) Thanks! I didn't think I needed to make it a function.

It is rather odd though, there are times that this fires and times that it doesn't! (In chrome anyway.) If you refresh the page 20 times, you will see sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.... how odd, right?

Comment: @PaulHanak that is odd.. but without the function `$(this)` is not referring to the current element.. which wouldn't work as you wanted.  By using the callback function `this` refers to each specific element so the height of each .packagepic will rely on what you return in the function

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".packagepic").css('height', function () {
    return $(this).parent().parent().height();
});
```

You might also set the width to `auto`, so as to keep the aspect ratio.